# Transpose Subdivided and Imported Data

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to transpose two data sets for `ListLinePlot`. Set 1 is imported from an Excel file, and the second set is created by `Subdivide`. When I try to transpose for `ListLinePlot` as a representative x and y plot, I see the error: "First two levels cannot be transposed". I tried to use `MatrixForm` but the result is the same. The sample code is below.

```
time = Import["D:/example.csv", {"Data", 1 ;; 1000000, 3}];
u = Subdivide[0, 10, 10];
w = Take[time, 10]; 
Transpose[{u, w}];
```

Comment: Should `Transpose[{v, y}];` be using `u` and `w` instead? What are the `Dimensions` of the two things you are trying to Transpose?

Comment: Thats right, 'u' and 'w', thank you. The dimensions are 1M for both. I used Matrix form so turned {1M,1}.

Comment: Please review the documentation for [`Subdivide`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html). `Subdivide[x1, x2, n]` makes a list of length **`n + 1`**, not **`n`**, where `n` is the number of subdivisions in the resulting list. The means you should use `u = Subdivide[0, 10, 9]` to make a list of 10 subdivided steps.

Comment: @creidhne thank you so much, that was the problem.